# maven jgitflow release-start goal changes line endings to CRLF

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jgit, line-endings

I'm working on Windows machine on a project which has line endings set to LF.
After the command `jgitflow:release-start` is run, poms are update with new versions, but also line-endings in poms are changed to CRLF.
Just to mention there is a line `*.xml text eol=lf` in .gitattributes.

Does anyone has idea how to prevent this?

Comment: This is done by git, take a look at this article - https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/. Be aware that jgit (and jgitflow) doesn't support `.gitattributes`, that is why there is `gitflow-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a ticket to improve line-endings handling in jGit flow plugin [here](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-183)

Currently, jgit flow chooses the EOL to use based on the global GIT config for **core.eol**. In my case adding `core.eol=lf` solves the problem.

Comment: The ticket of jGit flow you mentioned is solved meanwhile. So I tried to set `pom.xml text eol=lf`in project file `.gitattributes`. Unfortiuantelly the latest jGit-flow version `1.0-m5.1` still changes line endings of pom.xml under windows from `lf` to `crlf`. However globally setting `core.eol=lf`works.

Comment: Note that according to the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreeol) `core.eol` "value is ignored if `core.autocrlf` is set to true"